# Scrapy: how to return a new request after request.meta['proxy'] is changed?

Tags: proxy, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm crawling some pages with a few proxies, but some of the proxies don't work well and get

```
DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET http://xiyuanxiaoqu0571.fang.com/xiangqing/>
```

or

```
DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET http://yilexincun.fang.com/xiangqing/>
```

below is my spider.py and in parse_community() I tried to recrawl the pages whose response.status is not 200 but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Besides, how can I exclude the bad proxy ips which caused "http 302/403" when running the crawler?

```
#-*- coding=utf8 -*-

import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from soufang.items import Community_info
from scrapy import log
import sys 
import random
from soufang.misc.proxy import PROXIES
from imp import reload
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding( "utf-8" )


class soufangSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'soufang'
    allowed_domains = ['fang.com']
    start_urls = ['http://esf.hz.fang.com/housing/151_2352_1_0_0_0_1_0_0/']

    rules = (
             Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/xiangqing/$'),deny=    ('/\d.+\.html')),callback='parse_community'),
             Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/xiangqing/$'),deny=('/\d.+\.html'),restrict_xpaths = (u"//div[@class='info rel floatl ml15']/dl/dd[@id='detail_6']")),follow=True),
             Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=('/\d.+\.html'),restrict_xpaths = u"//a[text()='下一页']"))
         )

    handle_httpstatus_list = [302,404,503,403] 



    def parse_community(self,response):

        if response.status != 200 : 
           print response.url
           request = scrapy.Request(response.url)
           p = random.choice(PROXIES)
           request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % p
           return request


        item = Community_info()

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/div[@class='ewmBoxTitle']/span[@class='floatl']/text()").extract()
        item['community'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        item['city'] = ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='开 发 商：']/../text()").extract()
        item['developer'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='所属区域：']/../text()").extract()
        item['district'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='小区地址：']/../text()").extract()
        item['address'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='邮${nbsp}${nbsp}${nbsp}${nbsp}编：']/../text()").extract()
        item['postcode'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='竣工时间：']/../text()").extract()
        item['yearOfDev'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='firstpic']/dd[text()='本月均价：']/span[1]/text()").extract()
        item['price'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='总 户 数：']/../text()").extract()
        item['household_no'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='物业类别：']/../text()").extract()
        item['community_type'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='物 业 费：']/../text()").extract()
        item['property_fee'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='建筑面积：']/../text()").extract()
        item['total_area'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='占地面积：']/../text()").extract()
        item['area'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='绿 化 率：']/../text()").extract()
        item['greening_rate'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/dl[@class='lbox']/dd/strong[text()='容 积 率：']/../text()").extract()
        item['volumn_rate'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/div[@class='yihang']/h3[text()='交通状况']/../following-sibling::dl[1]/dt[1]/text()").extract()
        item['transportation'] = temp[0] if temp else ''

        temp = "".join(response.xpath(u"//div[@class='maininfo']/div[@class='leftinfo']/div[@class='yihang']/h3[text()='周边信息']/../following-sibling::dl[1]//text()").extract())
        item['periphery'] = temp if temp else ''


        log.msg(':'.join([response.url,item['community']]),level=log.INFO)

        return item
```

Comment: So, this is a hard enough problem that there are products like [Crawlera](http://scrapinghub.com/crawlera/) that specifically address it, transparently for your crawl. You can roll your own solution of course, but it will be a bit involved.